# Reference an Element in a List of Tuples

Tags: python, list, reference, element, tuples

Sorry in advance, but I'm new to Python.  I have a list of `tuples`, and I was wondering how I can reference, say, the first element of each `tuple` within the list.  I would think it's something like

```
for i in number_of_tuples :
  first_element = myList[i[0]]
```

you know, `[list_element[tuple_element]]`?  However, this doesn't appear to be the right approach.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Turner

Comment: myList[i][0] or more fun: [i[0] for i in myList]

Answer (score 48):

All of the other answers here are correct but do not explain why what you were trying was wrong. When you do `myList[i[0]]` you are telling Python that `i` is a tuple and you want the value or the first element of tuple `i` as the index for myList.

In the majority of programming languages when you need to access a nested data type (such as arrays, lists, or tuples), you append the brackets to get to the innermost item. The first bracket gives you the location of the tuple in your list. The second bracket gives you the location of the item in the tuple.

This is a quick rudimentary example that I came up with:

```
info = [ ( 1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6) ]

info[0][0] == 1
info[0][1] == 2
info[1][0] == 3
info[1][1] == 4
info[2][0] == 5
info[2][1] == 6
```

Comment: I wonder whether this answer has a higher computational cost than the list comprehension answer? The latter certainly has a higher memory cost!

Answer (score 31):

You can get a list of the first element in each tuple using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> my_tuples = [(1, 2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), (True, False), 'qwerty']
>>> first_elts = [x[0] for x in my_tuples]
>>> first_elts
[1, 'a', True, 'q']
```

Comment: what if I want to access all the elements of the tuple, like I have a list = [(1,2), (3,4) ,(5,6)]. I want to get 1, 2 both and then 3,4 and so on.. And not just the first or the last element.

Comment: @Liza `for x in my_tuples`...?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454390/how-to-flatten-a-list-of-tuples-into-a-pythonic-list

Answer (score 5):

The code

```
my_list = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
for t in my_list:
    print t
```

prints

```
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
(5, 6)
```

The loop iterates over `my_list`, and assigns the elements of `my_list` to `t` one after the other.  The elements of `my_list` happen to be tuples, so `t` will always be a tuple.  To access the first element of the tuple `t`, use `t[0]`:

```
for t in my_list:
    print t[0]
```

To access the first element of the tuple at the given index `i` in the list, you can use

```
print my_list[i][0]
```

Comment: is this for python 2? If so is there a similar version for python 3

Comment: @imantha This is Python 2. In Python 3, simply call `print()` with parentheses, everything else in this answer remains unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

You also can use [itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html?highlight=itemgetter#operator.itemgetter) operator:

```
from operator import itemgetter
my_tuples = [('c','r'), (2, 3), ('e'), (True, False),('text','sample')]
map(itemgetter(0), my_tuples)
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than:

```
first_element = myList[i[0]]
```

You probably want:

```
first_element = myList[i][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have "a list of tuples", let me assume that you are manipulating some 2-dimension matrix, and, in this case, one convenient interface to accomplish what you need is the one `numpy` provides.

Say you have an array `arr = numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])`, you can use `arr[:, 0]` to get a new array of all the first elements in each "tuple".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example:

```
termList = []
termList.append(('term1', [1,2,3,4]))
termList.append(('term2', [5,6,7,8]))
termList.append(('term3', [9,10,11,12]))

result = [x[1] for x in termList if x[0] == 'term3']

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

With my approach you do not need to import any module, it is more pythonic since it uses python´s native features:

```
list_of_tuples = [('a1', 'b1','c1'), ('a2', 'b2','c2'), ('a3', 'b3','c3')]

print(list(map(lambda x: x[0], list_of_tuples)))
>> ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']

print(list(map(lambda x: x[2], list_of_tuples)))
>> ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
```

By following this logic you can carry out other operations such as getting a particular item from a list of dictionaries, etc.