# How to flatten a list of tuples into a pythonic list

Tags: python, list, flatten

Given the following list of tuples:

```
INPUT = [(1,2),(1,),(1,2,3)]
```

How would I flatten it into a list?

```
OUTPUT ==> [1,2,1,1,2,3]
```

Is there a one-liner to do the above?

Similar: [Flatten list of Tuples in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994124/flatten-list-of-tuples-in-python)

Comment: Flattening a list of tuples can be done in exactly the same ways to flattening a list of lists. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python, and many other answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> INPUT = [(1,2),(1,),(1,2,3)]
>>> [y for x in INPUT for y in x]
[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

[`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) is also used a lot in cases like this:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> INPUT = [(1,2),(1,),(1,2,3)]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(INPUT))
[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

That's not exactly a one-liner though.

Comment: I tried this with str values, and it appears to see the strings as collection of characters (which makes sense), any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> INPUT = [(1,2),(1,),(1,2,3)]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(INPUT))
[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `sum` which adds up all of the elements if it's a list of list (singly-nested).

```
sum([(1,2),(1,),(1,2,3)], ())
```

or convert to list:

```
list(sum([(1,2),(1,),(1,2,3)], ()))
```

Adding up lists works in python.

**Note**: This is **very** inefficient and some say unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> INPUT = [(1,2),(1,),(1,2,3)]  
>>> import operator as op
>>> reduce(op.add, map(list, INPUT))
[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This has quadratic behaviour (if you make the list ten times longer, it will be one hundred times slower) and so won't be a good idea for long lists.

Comment: I agree, it's much much better to use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

Answer (score 0):

Not in one line but in two:

```
>>> out = []
>>> map(out.extend, INPUT)
... [None, None, None]
>>> print out
... [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Declare a list object and use extend.