# ordered dictionary python with enumeration

Tags: python

I have created an ordered dictionary in python and enumeration is used for for loop index. It gives following result exactly the way i wanted.

```
def get_stocks():
    tickers = OrderedDict()
    for ticker in enumerate(sorted(df_symbol.Symbol)):
        tickers[ticker] = "AlphaVantage"
    return tickers
```

It gets me this which is what I need.

```
OrderedDict([((0, 'HINDALCO'), 'AlphaVantage'), ((1, 'LUPIN'), 'AlphaVantage'), ((2, 'SUNPHARMA'), 'AlphaVantage')])
```

Now I want to print something like this from above. I am not successful:

```
['HINDALCO', 'LUPIN', 'SUNPHARMA']
```

I am doing something like this:

```
tickers = get_stocks()
ticker_list = list(tickers.keys())
```

I am getting:

```
[(0, 'HINDALCO'), (1, 'LUPIN'), (2, 'SUNPHARMA')]
```

Comment: More precisely:https://stackoverflow.com/a/6455332/3125566

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension.

```
ticker_list = [name for number, name in get_stocks().keys()]
```